# Using Multiple ANDs and ORs in ANSI SQL

Tags: sql, select

I have a simple SQL query:

```
SELECT
    w.fizz
FROM
    widgets w
WHERE
    w.special_id = 2394
    AND w.buzz IS NOT NULL
    AND w.foo = 12
```

In pseudo-code, this `WHERE` clause could be thought of as:

```
if(specialId == 2394 && buzz != null && foo == 12)
```

I now want to change this query so that it returns all widgets whose special_id is 2394, and whose buzz is not null, and whose foo is 12, **OR** whose special_id is 2394, and whose blah is 'YES', and whose num is 4. In pseudo-code:

```
if(specialId == 2394 && (buzz != null && foo == 12) || (blah == "YES" && num == 4))
```

I tried the following, only to get errors:

```
SELECT
    w.fizz
FROM
    widgets w
WHERE
    w.special_id = 2394
    AND
    (
        w.buzz IS NOT NULL
        AND w.foo = 12
    )
    OR
    (
        w.blah = 'YES'
        AND w.num = 4
    )
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    w.fizz
FROM
    widgets w
WHERE
    w.special_id = 2394
    AND
    (
        (
            w.buzz != null
            AND w.foo = 12
        )
        OR
        (
            w.blah = 'YES'
            AND w.num = 4
        )
    )
```

Add additional brackets surrounding "OR", because "OR" has less priority than "AND".